# Unable to upload files under mentioned blob using C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

Need to upload file under mentioned blob storage. example a/b/test.xlsx, when I tried below code file was uploading successfully but not in a/b. it is uploading in container.
Note: Already I have path in cloud which is a/b and in my C drive I have test.xlsx file.

please help me on this.

```
    static string connectionString = "myconnection string";
    static string containerName = "a/b";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName);

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/root");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
            {
                containerClient.UploadBlob(Path.GetFileName(file), stream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(file + "Uploaded");


        }
        Console.Read();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've *assumed* you're working with Azure blob storage and have added that tag. If that's incorrect, please remove that tag but find an appropriate tag *for the blob storage system you're working with*.

Comment: "a/b" is not a valid container name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata

Answer (score 0):

***I tried in my environment which I uploaded files in specific  path in the container.***

I have created storage account with container name and subfolder:

[image]

When I try below code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
namespace blobstorage
    {
        class Program
        {
            private const string connectionString = "Connection string";
            private const string containerName = "container name";
            private const string directoryPath = @"C:\root";
            static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                for (var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    var file = files[i];
                    var blobName = file.Replace(directoryPath, "subfolder name").Replace("\\", "/");
                    BlockBlobClient blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
                    using (var filesto = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        await blobClient.UploadAsync(filesto);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

When I run the above code I uploaded successfully thread.xlsx  in the specific blob folder:

[image]