# How to upload a file to an existing BLOB storage using C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I tried with sample code but it didn't work. Please help me on this.Example I have container folder-a/folder-b, now I have to upload csv  to folder-b

```
    static string connectionString = "myconnection string";
    static string containerName = "folder-a/folder-b";
    static void Main(string[] args)
     {
       BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
       BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName);

      var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/root");
      foreach (var file in files)
      {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
        {
            containerClient.UploadBlob(Path.GetFileName(file), stream);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(file + "Uploaded");


    }
    Console.Read();


}
```

}

Comment: "it didn't work" - what does this mean? Did you get a compile error ? Which? Or a runtime exception? Which? Or is the result not as you exected? How?

Comment: The file was uploaded in container but it has to upload under folder-b. I have container called folder-a under this I have one more directory which is folder-b. the file has to place under folder-b

Comment: Your containerName should be 'folder-a'. 'folder-a/folder-b' is not a valid container name. Your file name should be prefixed with the folder of your choice. So --> 'folder-b/' + file name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to upload files under mentioned blob using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73414818/unable-to-upload-files-under-mentioned-blob-using-c-sharp)